# Re-Direct To Webpage After Facebook Comment Is Placed

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am planning on installing the Facebook Comments module/plugin on a web page, let's say:

http://www.example.com/

Is it possible to re-direct users to another landing page within the site?  Let's say I want to send them here after clicking to post the comment:

http://www.example.com/landing-page/

Is this possible with either Facebook API or another script?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the comment.create event which fires when a user adds a comment like this:

Init

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId  : 'sensored-app-id',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});

/* All the events registered */
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function (response) {
    // Redirect to http://www.example.com/landing-page/
    window.location = "http://www.example.com/landing-page/";
});



};

(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
 e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/fi_FI/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

And in your fb comment you must set notify="true" like so

```
<fb:comments numposts="10" notify="true"></fb:comments>
```